# Internal Realtek microphone_array not working

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone, recording

As the title suggests what problem I am facing,I am hoping for some clue how to proceed. No matter which app, the microphone does not record anything but when using an earphone microphone to record, it works fine.

My Laptop is ASUS TUF GAMING FX504GD_FX80GD which is pre installed with Windows 10 Home Single (64 bit) and here is what I did so far:
- Downloaded the Realtek Audio driver from the ASUS's site, but still problem exists
- changed the property from the microphone array to stereo mix from the sound properties section(Control panel>Sound>Recording) randomly as thought tweaking something would help(earlier it was set to Microphone Array) but still the problem exists

Below is the replica of the Control Panel>Sound>Recording(can't post the the screenshot because not enough reputation points):

---

Sound

Recording

Select a recording device below to modify its settings:

Microphone Array

{

Realtek High Definiton  Audio

Default Device

}

Stereo Mix

{

Realtek High Definition Audio

Ready

}

---

Tried checking the drivers of the audio input and output and the sound,video and audio controller section, but according to me the necessary drivers are present. Both of the sections somewhat looks like this(can't post the screenshot as my reputation points is not 10):

---

-Audio inputs and outputs

```
 - Microphone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio)

 - Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)

 - Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)
```

and

-Sound,video and game controllers

```
 - Intel(R) Display Audio


 - Realtek High Definition Audio
```

---

Alternate apps used for recording other than the default Windows recorder but still no use:

- FonepawScreen recorder
- Mirillis Action!

Below is the system information:

```
        Machine name: DESKTOP-MSTO86Q
           Machine Id: {2DC63750-F428-4798-95A6-4B55AB6D5692}
     Operating System: Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit (10.0, Build 18362) (18362.19h1_release.190318-1202)
             Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
  System Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
         System Model: TUF GAMING FX504GD_FX80GD
                 BIOS: FX504GD.315 (type: UEFI)
            Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8300H CPU @ 2.30GHz (8 CPUs), ~2.3GHz
               Memory: 8192MB RAM
  Available OS Memory: 8048MB RAM
            Page File: 5936MB used, 4031MB available
          Windows Dir: C:\Windows
      DirectX Version: DirectX 12
  DX Setup Parameters: Not found
     User DPI Setting: 120 DPI (125 percent)
   System DPI Setting: 120 DPI (125 percent)
      DWM DPI Scaling: UnKnown
             Miracast: Available, with HDCP
```

Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Supported
 DirectX Database Version: 1.1.0

### DxDiag Version: 10.00.18362.0387 64bit Unicode

### Sound Capture Devices

```
        Description: Microphone Array (Realtek High Definition Audio)
```

Default Sound Capture: Yes
  Default Voice Capture: Yes
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.8656 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 3/25/2019 00:08:40, 6781216 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x1
           Format Flags: 0xFFFFF

```
        Description: Stereo Mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)
```

Default Sound Capture: No
  Default Voice Capture: No
            Driver Name: RTKVHD64.sys
         Driver Version: 6.00.0001.8656 (English)
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
          Date and Size: 3/25/2019 00:08:40, 6781216 bytes
              Cap Flags: 0x1
           Format Flags: 0xFFFFF

Sorry for the wrong formations if present any and let me know  if any details missed out.Thank you.